# Как сделать span c border-radius на каждой строке?

Tags: css, border, span

[image: Вот что должно получится!]

Должно получиться то, что выше. А получается только вначале и в конце строки, да еще и без border и shadows. И в ручную делить текст на разные строки не вариант: Контент генерируется пользователем. Я даже не знаю можно ли тут обойтись css.

Comment: на css пожалуй нельзя.

Comment: нужно каждую строку чем то обгорнуть и с помощью js проверять верхнюю и нижнюю строку на количество символов.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, только при помощи js. Идея примерно такая:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var rects = span.getClientRects();

var d = `M ${rects[0].left} ${rects[0].top} `;

for (var q=0; q<rects.length; ++q) {
  d += `H ${rects[q].right} V ${rects[q].bottom} `;
}

for (var q=rects.length-1; q>-1; --q) {
  d += `H ${rects[q].left} V ${rects[q].top} `;
}

d += 'Z';

var p = span.parentElement;
var bb = p.getBoundingClientRect();

var svg = `<svg viewBox="${bb.left} ${bb.top} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}">
  <path d="${d}" />
</svg>`;

p.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', svg);
```

```css
body {
  width: 638px;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  color: blue;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: visible;
}

path {
  fill: antiquewhite;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции <span>читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации</span>  "Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.."</p>
```

Comment: не правильно, здесь нет закругленных углов.

Comment: @Abmin, но можно добавить. Я показал идею, как в принципе это можно сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy А как же теперь добавить скругления отступы от текста? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Это нужно в svg что-то прописать? rx не работает.

Comment: @DenisKozlov, для скруглений надо использовать `a` в нужную сторону. При этом надо смотреть, делается поворот вправо или влево и отдельно обрабатывать случай, когда горизонтальное расстояние меньше удвоенного радиуса. А что касается отступа - просто прибавить или вычесть некоторую константу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо